# Add existing field to Approval workflow's approval form

Tags: workflow

I want to add a existing site column or a custom developed field to OTB Approval Workflow's approval form, so that approver have to fill that additional field.

Can this be done without modifying the form?
Please let me know how that can be achieved.

Thanks,
Amit